# Minimum/minimal element

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that (A,R) is a poset.

(a) Assume that b is the minimum element of (A,R). Prove that if c∈A, and c is minimal element of (A,R), then c=b.

Proof: Assume that b is the minimum element of (A,R) and c∈A is minimal.
Then bRa for all a∈A, then bRc.
And cRa for all a∈A, where c≠a. Then cRb.
Therefore, b=c.

(b) Prove that if d is minimal in (A,R) and d is the only minimal element of (A,R) and d is comparable with every element of A, then d is the minimum element of (A,R).

Proof: Assume that d is the only minimal element of (A,R) and d is comparable with every element of A. 
Then dRa for all d≠a, a∈A. 
Then dRa for all a∈A.
Therefore, D is minimum element of (A,R)

Am I doing it right? I am not sure why we need and assumption d is comparable with every element of A in (b).

Comment: In statement $(b)$, $d$ must be comparable. Let $d$  was an alone point. in this case there is not reason that $d$ was minimum. An element can be minimum iff when it was comparable.

Comment: @Artin: Statement (a) is true: $b$ is *minimum*, not *minimal*.

Comment: Oh yes, because b is $minimum$ it is comparable with $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of (a) isn’t quite right. The fact that $c$ is minimal does not mean that $c\mathbin{R}a$ for all $a\in A\setminus\{c\}$; it means that there is no $a\in A\setminus\{c\}$ such that $a\mathbin{R}c$. However, we know that $b\mathbin{R}c$, so $b\notin A\setminus\{c\}$, and of course $b\in A$, so $b\in A\setminus\big(A\setminus\{c\}\big)=\{c\}$, and therefore $b=c$.

In the proof of (b) let $a\in A\setminus\{d\}$ be arbitrary; $d$ is comparable with $a$, so either $d\mathbin{R}a$, or $a\mathbin{R}d$. Since $d$ is minimal, we know that it’s not the case that $a\mathbin{R}d$, so it must be the case that $d\mathbin{R}a$. Of course $d\mathbin{R}d$, so $d\mathbin{R}a$ for each $a\in A$, and $d$ is therefore the minimum element of $A$. The hypothesis that $d$ is the only minimal element of $A$ is unnecessary, and you’ll notice that I didn’t use it.

To see why the comparability assumption is needed, let $A=\{d\}\cup\{a(n):n\in\Bbb N\}$, and define $R$ as follows by setting $a(m)\mathbin{R}a(n)$ if and only if $m\ge n$, $d\mathbin{R}x$ if and only if $x=d$, and $x\mathbin{R}d$ if and only if $x=d$. Thus, $d$ is not comparable with any of the $a(n)$. Check that $R$ is a partial order on $A$, that $d$ is the only minimal element in $A$, and that $A$ has no minimum element. A Hasse diagram may help:

```
               d *            * a(0)  
                              |  
                              * a(1)  
                              |  
                              * a(2)  
                              |  
                              * a(3)  
                              |  
                              .  
                              .  
                              .  
                              |  
                              * a(n)  
                              |  
                              * a(n+1)  
                              |  
                              .  
                              .  
                              .
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, wow it's so clear and beautiful.

Comment: @Nadia: You’re welcome!